# ¿Cómo se escribe el grito de Chimo Bayo?

Tags: pronunciación

Chimo Bayo es un <s>personaje</s> productor de música electrónica que se hizo famoso en los 90 con éxitos como *Así me gusta a mí* y *Bombas*.

En el primero de ellos, Chimo introduce el que será su grito más conocido, y que [podéis escuchar aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_lLPZKfkc8&t=55). Tan conocido es, que el propio artista ha bautizado así a [un vino](http://www.lomejordelvinoderioja.com/vino-huha-chimo-20180302105007-nt.html) para darle publicidad.

Como podéis ver, en ocasiones este grito se transcribe como "HU-HA"... pero técnicamente, puesto que la H en español es sorda, eso se pronunciaría `/u//a/`. Tampoco "JU-JA" sería adecuado, ya que la J suena demasiado fuerte. La pronunciación que hace Chimo es algo más suave, parecida al sonido inglés de *how*, *high*, etc.

La pregunta es: ¿hay alguna manera en español de transcribir una expresión así?

Comment: Solo con ver el título de la pregunta me dije: "este tío ha visto lo del vino 'Hu-ha' de Chimo Bayo". :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí, técnicamente la *h* en español es sorda... o casi. Consultando el artículo para la letra *h* en el DPD podemos leer [la siguiente información](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=h):

> [..] hasta mediados del siglo XVI se pronunciaba, en determinados casos (concretamente cuando procedía de *f* inicial latina), de forma parecida a como se pronuncia hoy la *h* aspirada inglesa [...].

De hecho en algunos casos la pronunciación viró hacia la *j* como en el caso de *jondo*, *jalar* o *jolgorio*. Sigue:

> En algunos extranjerismos usados corrientemente en español (tomados, por lo general, del inglés o del alemán, pero también de otras lenguas como el árabe), así como en algunos nombres propios extranjeros y sus derivados, la *h* se pronuncia también aspirada o con sonido cercano al de /j/ [...].

Y pone como ejemplo una palabra española de pleno derecho, con grafía adaptada y todo: *hámster*. No conozco a nadie que pronuncie "ámster". Otro ejemplo es *hachís*, que si le quitas la primera *h* aspirada parece que estás estornudando.

Con todo esto quiero decir que el español ya contempla casos de palabras incluso adaptadas a la grafía española, con *h* inicial pero pronunciada aspirada. Luego en principio no debería ser incorrecto escribir ese grito tal y como lo han hecho en el vino: *hu-ha*.

La *Ortografía 2010* tiene un párrafo ([el 6.1.3.2](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=hGEWbyvCQZvDPKQk)) dedicado por completo al estudio de la *h* aspirada. En este se puede leer:

> Aunque ya se ha visto que, en su mayoría, estas haches [que se aspiraban en su idioma de origen, cita como ejemplo *alcohol*, *harén*, *hamburguesa*, *hotentote* y *harakiri* por poner algunos, incluso topónimos como *Holanda*] no se pronuncian hoy en el español general, en algunos casos, especialmente en los préstamos más recientes, puede conservarse la aspiración característica de la lengua de la que proceden.

Y a los ejemplos del DPD añade otros como *dírham*, *hándicap*, *haiku* y topónimos extranjeros como *Hawái* o *Hong Kong*.

Por supuesto, el caso de *hu-ha* es especial porque no es una palabra de origen extranjero, sino un neologismo, una palabra inventada por su autor que quiso que se pronunciara así. Lo que quiero decir es, simplemente, que las haches aspiradas no son extrañas en nuestro idioma, y que la *h* es la forma correcta de representar ese sonido, tanto por su historia como por la influencia de idiomas extranjeros, los cuales hoy día no resultan tan extraños como antiguamente.

Es posible que en algún sitio hayas visto una hache en superíndice para representar ese sonido, pero es solo [una representación fonética](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspiraci%C3%B3n_(fon%C3%A9tica)):

> En fonética, la aspiración es una fuerte explosión de aire que acompaña a la relajación (o el inicio en el caso de la preaspiración) de una obstruyente. El signo diacrítico para denotar la aspiración en el Alfabeto Fonético Internacional (AFI) es un superíndice "h", [ʰ].