# ¿Cuáles son las excepciones a la norma de usar "el" delante de sustantivos femeninos que empiezan por "a" tónica?

Tags: gramática, artículos

Buscando información para *[¿Cómo se escribe el grito de Chimo Bayo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24426/12637)* leo en el DPD [lo siguiente](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=h) acerca de la letra hache:

> Su nombre es femenino: *la hache* (es una de las excepciones a la regla que exige el empleo de la forma *el* del artículo ante sustantivos femeninos que comienzan por /a/ tónica).

Me quedé ciertamente extrañado porque, efectivamente, decimos *la hache* pero también *el hacha*. ¿Cuáles son estas excepciones a la regla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El mismo DPD nos da la respuesta en su entrada para [el artículo *el*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=el):

- Se usa *la* y no *el* ante los nombres de las letras *a*, *hache* y *alfa*.
- Se usa ante los nombres propios de mujer, cuando llevan artículo ("la Ana" y no "el Ana").
- Se usa ante las siglas, cuando el núcleo de la denominación no abreviada (normalmente, la palabra representada por la primera letra de la sigla) es un sustantivo femenino que no comienza por /a/ tónica. Así, le dice "la APA" (Asociación de Padres de Alumnos) porque *asociación* no empieza por *a* tónica.
- En el caso de los sustantivos que comienzan por /a/ tónica y designan seres sexuados, si tienen una única forma, válida para ambos géneros, se mantiene el uso de la forma *la* del artículo cuando el referente es femenino, ya que este es el único modo de señalar su sexo: *la árabe*, *la ácrata*. Esto no afecta si el sustantivo posee ambas formas: *el amo* y *el ama*. Excepción a la excepción: si la forma femenina es de creación reciente, se está usando espontáneamente *la*, como en *la árbitra*. Resulta curiosa la explicación de la excepción a la excepción:

  > Es muy probable que la razón de que los hablantes digan, espontáneamente, *la árbitra* (y no *el árbitra*) sea que, perdida ya toda conciencia de que la forma *el* ante nombres femeninos procede, por evolución, de un femenino *ela*, en el sistema actual, la forma *el* se asocia exclusivamente con el género masculino y *la* con el femenino; quizá por ello, en los nuevos usos, cuando el sustantivo se refiere a seres sexuados, tiende a rechazarse la aplicación de la antigua norma.
- Cuando el artículo acompaña a topónimos femeninos que comienzan por /a/ tónica, el uso es fluctuante. Así, con continentes se dice *el África*, *el Asia*, pero con países y ciudades se prefiere *la*: *La Haya* (aquí el artículo forma incluso parte del nombre), *la Ámsterdam*, *la Austria*.

Comment: Carla es el Aria mas inteligetne que he visto ...suena feo